# How to manually terminate a task in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code gives us the ability to set up tasks in tasks.json. I've seen people use the "watch" tasks, but don't know how to terminate them manually. The only way I've done it was to attempt to start the same task again which prompts me to terminate the running task. Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this?

I'm on OS X.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's currently no key shortcut to terminate a running task. You can, however create your own shortcut for it. Go to **File**->**Preferences**->**Keyboard Shortcuts** and add your shortcut to the `keybindings.json`.

Here's example code:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate"
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I ended up with the following combination:
`[ { "key": "alt+t", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask" }, { "key": "shift+alt+t", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate" } ]`

Comment: have tried, but it keep asking which task to terminate while there is only one python file is running. and the program does not stop.

Answer (score 9):

To add a solution in windows:

Extension: Code Runner

Command: Stop code run

Keybinding: Ctrl Alt M

Editor Version: 1.23.1

It could be similar in MacOS, perhaps you need to replace Ctrl to the Command Key.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although this might answer the question, consider adding explanation/links to support your answer!

Comment: In macOS, it is  CTRL-ALT-M too.

Comment: Not working for me. My program still printing the output indefinitely.

Comment: @h0lmes221B: Did you install the extension Code Runner from the marketplace? It has the shortcut CTRL-ALT-M as default.  Check your shortcut by looking at Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts and then search for `stop code run`.

Answer (score 2):

Go to file->preferences->keyboard shortcuts
then search for "kill terminal" by default no key would be assigned to it, double click on it assign a key then hit enter
now use that shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to @coffee_addict's answer, to kill all tasks with a keybinding (without a prompt) you can add the "terminateAll" argument to the object in `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate",
    "args": "terminateAll"
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27041#issuecomment-482620400

Answer (score 1):

To add a shortcut for "Terminate Task" in Visual Studio 1.30.2 in Windows:

Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts (or Ctrl + K and then Ctrl + S)
Scroll all the way down, almost to the end of the list 
(past "workbench.action.* etc), 
until there's the list of suggested actions with no content in column "Keybinding".
Locate the row with Command "Terminate Task", 
click on it to make it active, and then press the + -sign in front of it.
Type in a suitable Shortcut, e.g. Ctrl + Alt + T , and press enter.

Now the "Terminate Task" command is on the first part of the Keyboard Shortcuts list
(with text "User" in the column Source), and you can use it in the terminal. 
If needed, you can still edit the Keybinding by clicking on the icon "Change Keybinding" at the first column of the row.

Answer (score 0):

For running python code, give focus to the terminal window and press control C (Ctrl+C), this generates a keyboard interrupt which stops the interpreter, unless your code handles such interrupts some other way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a square shaped stop button that displays at the top right corner of the vscode window when a code is still running, simply click it to stop the current code running